# Unmet Dependencies on QGIS after upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 Ubuntu

Tags: qgis, python, installation

I updated my computer from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04.  The 18.04 computer had a happy installation of QGIS 3.16 with SAGA.  After the upgrade I lost QGIS.  Thinking I needed to do a new installation I followed the [installation instructions](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu) for QGIS 3.18.  This installation returned the following error.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
qgis : Depends: python3-qgis (= 1:3.18.3+32focal) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I did an `autoremove` and tried the installation again and got the same error message of unmet dependencies.

Assuming some error in the instructions or the repository I went ahead with the etc/apt/sources.list approach and tried to install 3.16.  Here are the relevant lines of the sources.list.

```
deb https://qgis.org/ubuntu focal main
deb-src https://qgis.org/ubuntu focal main
```

After running

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install qgis qgis-plugin-grass
```

I got the same error message for unmet dependencies.

I tried a shot in the dark and tried.

```
sudo apt get install python3-qgis
```

and

```
pip3 install python3-qgis
```

This did not help after I ran the update again.

I found this post here and tried the installation using aptitude.
Here is the result of the aptitude attempt.

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
grass-core{a} grass-doc{a} libassimp5{a} libjs-leaflet{a} 
liblaszip8{a} 
libpdal-base9{a} libpdal-plugin-faux{a} libpdal-plugin-icebridge{a} 
libpdal-plugin-pgpointcloud{a} libpdal-plugin-python{a} 
libpdal-plugin-sqlite{a} libpdal-plugins{a} libpdal-util9{a} 
libpython3.8{ab} libqgis-3d3.18.3{a} libqgis-analysis3.18.3{a} 
libqgis-app3.18.3{a} libqgis-core3.18.3{a} libqgis-customwidgets{a} 
libqgis-gui3.18.3{a} libqgis-native3.18.3{a} libqgis-server3.18.3{a} 
libqgisgrass7-3.18.3{a} libqgispython3.18.3{a} libqt53danimation5{a} 
libqt53dcore5{a} libqt53dextras5{a} libqt53dinput5{a} libqt53dlogic5{a} 
libqt53dquickscene2d5{a} libqt53drender5{a} libqt5charts5{a} 
libspatialindex6{a} libsqlite3-mod-spatialite{a} libzip5{a} 
python3-attr{a} python3-decorator{a} python3-ipython-genutils{a} 
python3-jinja2{a} python3-jsonschema{a} python3-jupyter-core{a} 
python3-nbformat{a} python3-owslib{a} python3-plotly{a} 
python3-pygments{a} python3-pyproj{a} python3-pyqt5{a} 
python3-pyqt5.qsci{a} python3-pyqt5.qtsql{a} python3-pyqt5.qtsvg{a} 
python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit{a} python3-pyrsistent{a} python3-qgis{a} 
python3-qgis-common{a} python3-retrying{a} python3-traitlets{a} qgis 
qgis-common{a} qgis-plugin-grass qgis-plugin-grass-common{a} 
qgis-provider-grass{a} qgis-providers{a} qgis-providers-common{a} 
qml-module-qtcharts{a} qt3d-assimpsceneimport-plugin{a} 
qt3d-defaultgeometryloader-plugin{a} qt3d-gltfsceneio-plugin{a} 
qt3d-scene2d-plugin{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 68 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not 
upgraded.
Need to get 161 MB of archives. After unpacking 518 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libpython3.8 : Depends: libpython3.8-stdlib (= 3.8.5-1~20.04.2) but 
3.8.10-1+bionic1 is installed
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

  Keep the following packages at their current version:
```

1. ```
    libpdal-plugin-python [Not Installed]
   ```
2. ```
    libpdal-plugins [Not Installed]
   ```
3. ```
    libpython3.8 [Not Installed]
   ```
4. ```
    libqgispython3.18.3 [Not Installed]
   ```
5. ```
    python3-pyqt5 [Not Installed]
   ```
6. ```
    python3-pyqt5.qsci [Not Installed]
   ```
7. ```
    python3-pyqt5.qtsql [Not Installed]
   ```
8. ```
    python3-pyqt5.qtsvg [Not Installed]
   ```
9. ```
    python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit [Not Installed]
   ```
10. ```
    python3-qgis [Not Installed]
    ```
11. ```
    qgis [Not Installed]
    ```
12. ```
    qgis-plugin-grass [Not Installed]
    ```

    Leave the following dependencies unresolved:
13. ```
    libpdal-base9 recommends libpdal-plugins
    ```

    Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] Y
    No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
    0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
    Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.

How do I satisfy the unmet dependencies an install QGIS 3.16 (or 3.18) on Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: You have some leftover 18.04 python packages.  You need to replace the bionic python3.8* packages and install the focal ones. However... don't just apt remove them as your whole desktop depends on python 3.8 so you'll pretty much remove EVERYTHING!!!. If you have synaptic it's pretty easy to force install specific versions, but in the shell you could try something like `apt list *python3.8*` and then `sudo apt install libpython3.8-dev=3.8.5-1~20.04.2 libpython3.8-minimal=3.8.5-1~20.04.2 python3.8=etc...` for all `*python3.8*` packages that `apt list` shows are installed.

Comment: Thanks @user2856 when I try your suggestion I get 'The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpython3.8 : Depends: libpython3.8-stdlib (= 3.8.5-1~20.04.2) but 3.8.10-1+bionic1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.'

Comment: Did you include libpython3.8-stdlib=3.8.5-1~20.04.2 in your command?

Comment: I did  include libpython3.8-stdlib=3.8.5-1~20.04.2.  I ended up uninstalling Python and QGIS and reinstalling.  Everything is working fine now.

Comment: Glad to hear it.